# rake gems:install error cannot load such a file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rake, ruby-on-rails-2

Hi I am using ruby ruby 1.8.7 & Rails 2.3.2

I have added the necessary gem to config/environment

```
  config.gem "rack", :version => '1.0.1', :source => "https://rubygems.org"
  config.gem "tlsmail", :version => '0.0.1', :source => "https://rubygems.org"
  config.gem "tmail", :version => '1.2.3.1', :source => "https://rubygems.org"
  config.gem "rcodetools", :version => '0.8.5.0', :source => "https://rubygems.org"
  config.gem "linecache", :version => '0.43', :source => "https://rubygems.org"
  config.gem "ruby-debug-base", :version => '0.10.3', :source => "https://rubygems.org"
  config.gem "ruby-debug", :version => '0.10.3', :source => "https://rubygems.org"
  config.gem "mongrel", :version => '1.1.5', :source => "https://rubygems.org"
  config.gem "mongrel_cluster", :version => '1.0.5', :source => "https://rubygems.org"
  config.gem "passenger", :version => '2.2.4', :source => "https://rubygems.org"
  config.gem "chronic", :version => '0.3.0', :source => "https://rubygems.org"
```

when first time i run **rake gems:install** all the gem are installed successfully but when i add new gem and run  **rake gems:install**  it show the following  errors.

```
no such file to load -- rcodetools
    /home/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p374/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
    /home/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p374/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
    /home/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374@my_app/gems/activesupport-2.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
    /home/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374@my_app/gems/activesupport-2.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
    /home/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374@my_app/gems/activesupport-2.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
    /home/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374@my_app/gems/rails-2.3.2/lib/rails/gem_dependency.rb:179:in `load'
    /home/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374@my_app/gems/rails-2.3.2/lib/initializer.rb:305:in `load_gems'
    /home/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374@my_app/gems/rails-2.3.2/lib/initializer.rb:305:in `each'
    /home/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374@my_app/gems/rails-2.3.2/lib/initializer.rb:305:in `load_gems'
    /home/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374@my_app/gems/rails-2.3.2/lib/initializer.rb:162:in `process'
    /home/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374@my_app/gems/rails-2.3.2/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `send'
    /home/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374@my_app/gems/rails-2.3.2/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `run'
    /home/Desktop/my_app/config/environment.rb:9
```

can any one tell me what is the reason for error.

Thanks in advance

Comment: it's old application all code are write in rails 2 can you found what cause of error..

Comment: rails 2 has no support now, and gems have to be manually installed

Comment: okay thanks. :-). how to specif the gem and version for heroku deploy